# Mapping rendered HTML to line of code in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Im looking for a way to click on an HTML element in the rendered webpage in Chrome of my Vue.js app (running in dev mode) and see the line of code in the corresponding .vue file that generated it.  Is there a way to do this with Vue devtools?  If not, could I write an npm plugin to go through and maybe add a unique property to each HTML element in my code, to allow for the mapping to be defined?

Comment: If your components have gotten so big this is a problem for you, it's probably a sign you need some new sub-components...

Comment: [vue devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) support this to some extent. It will not jump to the line, but it will open the highlighted component in your editor. After installing the extension, you also need to follow the steps for [Open component in editor](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#open-component-in-editor).

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz - my components haven't gotten big, i'm just trying to figure out an easy way for non-developers to make quick changes to pieces of code.

Comment: @ljubadr i'm using vue devtools, and can see the highlighted component... not sure how devtools works to do that; if it's something I can extend I'd love to be able to do that

Comment: Take a look at the second link, open component in editor